# mod_wsgi with a read only filesystem - webserver can’t start

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, mod-wsgi

I’m using mod_wsgi to create a Python webserver.
It has been Dockerized and deployed to kubernetes with readonlyfilesystem=true.
The application can’t start because mod_wsgi tries to create files and folders in the tmp folder but it doesn’t have the permission.
It’s possible to do it?
There is eventually an alternative way to store these files?

Thanks

Comment: create a volume as empty dir type and mount it under /tmp :)

Comment: Hi @c4f4t0r, in this way the folder is writable. A malicious user with the same privileges of the user can write to tmp

Comment: but it's not able to write on rootFS, only on tmp, so you need to decide or find a way to say to the application to don't write, for example, if this application is writing logs on a specific file, this file could become a link to stdout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of readOnlyFileSystem is that the container should be immutable!
In some cases, you can create the file in the Dockerfile so the program can read it directly, without needing to create it but, usually, you would have to mount a volume or use Docker's temporary files systems.